# Which is faster? Multiplication in code, or multiplication in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Question:

What's faster:
Multiplying 2 doubles in a SQL table and return the table, or returning the table and multiplying two column values in code ?

You can assume that the two columns that need to be multiplied need to be returned anyway.

Comment: Test it, that's the only way to know for sure

Comment: Testing it is one way to find out, but if the number of operations isn't a very high, this micro-optimization will have little or no effect.

Comment: sql operations if possible carried out in Sql Server itself are prefered. For example, if you are inserting CSV files or XML files to db. So instead of doing lots of iterations , you can insert it at a time within a second with built in functionalities.... If the operations that are not possible in Sql server queries then send a preprocessed result or do it in code behinds... or what ever suits you best....

Comment: @RQDQ: Haha. If I have left a question unaccepted, that's because the question hasn't yet been answered with a USEFUL answer.

Comment: @All: The question really concerns reporting service on large tables.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication is an extremely fast computation, and whether the chip is asked to do it from SQL or from another places shouldnt make any differnce.  The thing that will probably make it quicker in SQL is that it can be done in a single pass (though that depends on how SQL implements it), where as if you do it in code you have to cycle through the result set, but then again you might be doing that anyway.

The real answer though is it really doesnt matter unless you plan to multiply 10's of millions of numbers at a time.

Comment: Not the multiplication but the possible hogging resources (if you dont read it all->then process/multiply in client code)

Answer (score 1):

SQL is faster IF you are

- using appropriate data types with efficient hardware arithmetic ([more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm))
- using join/view efficiently.

and generally
 - Avoid delimited fields ([more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_modes.htm#i1008335))

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen SQL process much slower than **native code** is when doing excessive powers and logs. Why, I don't know, as the CPU has the same amount of work to do either way.

The only possible reason is that T-SQL is a scripted language. You never mentioned what language you're using.

As mentioned by others, test.

The real answer is to only perform math on the records that need it. This you **should** achieve with SQL.

Of course, in the extreme, you could use SSE (or AVX with Sandy Bridge) in native code, which will of course yield significantly faster results. I don't believe SQL Server would be able to apply such optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL if you're doing it right!**

Answer (score 0):

In this case SQL, include the Mulitply as part of the select statement when you retrieve the resultset. If you are doing in code, then you will have to iterate through the resultset seperately which will be time consuming.

On the other hand if you are just returning two values and want to multiply that, it doesn't matter if its code or sql :)

Comment: if you return just 1 value, it's less data on the wire.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is to do it in code because the DBMS might be wrong.  SQL Server is known to get it wrong.

Try this and notice the scary difference between the two results:
select 1.0 * 3/2 
select 3/2 * 1.0

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. `select 3.0/2.0 * 1.0` is giving the exact same results. It's all about data types, same goes for e.g. C#.

Comment: 321X - You altered the query example I provided.  If you run this select statement: SELECT 3/2 * 1.0 --it returns 1.0.  If you run this select statement:  SELECT 1.0 * 3.2 -- it returns 1.500000.  SQL Server is clearly mathematically wrong.  And it is wrong because it rounds the first result to an integer.

Comment: Check e.g. C#: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hlHuV2 it’s exactly the same

Comment: Yes it is, and it is easier to manage in C# code than in T-SQL.  It is easier to write code to manage the rounding problem.  Therefore I still recommend doing the math in code over doing it in SQL.